# Building PHP from source for use in Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, php

I'm having trouble when installing an older version of PHP (5.1) on a Ubuntu machine. I've tried to downgrade it without success using apt-get, so I tried to install from source. After the installation, typing `php -v` in the terminal results in the correct version (i.e. 5.1), but the version that apache uses keep the same (the older one: 5.4) if I view it through `<?php phpinfo()`.

How do I add the installation I just did to apache in place of the older one?
I need to remove the older version and make apache recognize the version I just installed.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the older version's `so` files in apache's confs, and restart apache for it to take effect. On Ubuntu 14.04, see `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load`:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

Update above line in the file to point to the equivalent `so` for php 5.1.

Comment: How do I find the path for the new version installed from source?

Comment: That would depend on what flags you used to build PHP. Perhaps a build path or directory to build in? Look in that directory for a `.so` file. It *may* have a different name in PHP 5.1.